# efficiency vs. readability: obfuscation when using nested boolean index arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, readability

I have some pretty ugly indexing going on.  For example, things like

```
valid[ data[ index[valid[:,0],0] ] == 0, 1] = False
```

where `valid` and `index` are {Nx2} arrays or `bool`s and `int`s respectively, and `data` is {N} long.

If I concentrate really hard, I can convince myself that this is doing what I want...  but its incredibly obfuscated.  **How can I unobfuscate something like this efficiently?**

I could break it up, for example:

```
valid_index = index[valid[:,0],0]
invalid_index = (data[ valid_index ] == 0)
valid[ invalid_index, 1 ] = False
```

But my arrays will have up to 100's of millions of entries so I don't want to duplicate the memory; and I need to remain as speed efficient as possible.

Comment: You are not doing any extra copying anyway, so just do that (though I would prefer you skip the spaces at those brackets (PEP8)

Comment: @seberg I'm creating two new (large) arrays that aren't actually logically needed for functionality --- so that's extra memory, just like if I had suggested something like `valid_data = data[valid_index]`

Comment: Jeesh... that is just nonsense, you are creating those arrays anyway, the 3 lines do **exactly** the same thing.

Comment: @seberg it looks like you were totally right.  In the future including some type of explanatory information might be a little helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two code sequences are nearly identical, and should have very similar performance. That's my "gut feeling"--but then I did static analysis and ran a partial benchmark to confirm.

The clearer option requires four more bytecodes to implement, so will probably be slightly slower. But the extra work is restricted to `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST`, which are just moves from the top of stack (`TOS`) to/from variables. As the extra work is modest, so should be the performance impact.

You could benchmark the two approaches on your target equipment for more quantitative precision, but on my 3-year-old laptop, 100 million extra `LOAD_FAST` / `STORE_FAST` pairs takes just over 3 seconds on standard CPython 2.7.5. So I estimate this clarity will cost you about 6 seconds per 100M entries. While the [PyPy](http://pypy.org) just-in-time Python compiler doesn't use the same bytecodes, I timed its overhead for the clear version at about half that, or 3 seconds per 100M. Compared to other work you're doing to process the items, the clearer version probably is not a significant showdown.

**The TL;DR Backstory**

My first impression is that the code sequences, while different in readability and clarity, are technically very similar, and should not have similar performance characteristics. But let's analyze a bit further using the Python disassembler. I dropped each code snippet into a function:

```
def one(valid, data):
    valid[ data[ index[valid[:,0],0] ] == 0, 1] = False

def two(valid, data):
    valid_index = index[valid[:,0],0]
    invalid_index = (data[ valid_index ] == 0)
    valid[ invalid_index, 1 ] = False
```

Then using [Python's bytecode dissassember](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

```
import dis
dis.dis(one)
print "---"
dis.dis(two)
```

Gives:

```
15           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (False)
             3 LOAD_FAST                0 (valid)
             6 LOAD_FAST                1 (data)
             9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (index)
            12 LOAD_FAST                0 (valid)
            15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            21 BUILD_SLICE              2
            24 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            27 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            30 BINARY_SUBSCR       
            31 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            34 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            37 BINARY_SUBSCR       
            38 BINARY_SUBSCR       
            39 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            42 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
            45 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            48 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            51 STORE_SUBSCR        
            52 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            55 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

```
18           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (index)
             3 LOAD_FAST                0 (valid)
             6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            12 BUILD_SLICE              2
            15 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            18 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            21 BINARY_SUBSCR       
            22 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            25 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            28 BINARY_SUBSCR       
            29 STORE_FAST               2 (valid_index)

19          32 LOAD_FAST                1 (data)
            35 LOAD_FAST                2 (valid_index)
            38 BINARY_SUBSCR       
            39 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            42 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
            45 STORE_FAST               3 (invalid_index)

20          48 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
            51 LOAD_FAST                0 (valid)
            54 LOAD_FAST                3 (invalid_index)
            57 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            60 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            63 STORE_SUBSCR        
            64 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            67 RETURN_VALUE
```

Similar but not identical, and not in the same order. A quick [diff of the two](http://content.screencast.com/users/jonathaneunice/folders/Jing/media/f7571468-2aa2-4cc2-9610-714a29a9234f/00000453.png) shows the same, plus the possibility the clearer function requires more byte codes.

I parsed the bytecode opcodes out of each function's disassembler listing, dropped them into a `collections.Counter`, and compared the counts:

```
Bytecode       Count(s) 
========       ======== 
BINARY_SUBSCR  3        
BUILD_SLICE    1        
BUILD_TUPLE    3        
COMPARE_OP     1        
LOAD_CONST     7        
LOAD_FAST      3, 5     *** differs ***
LOAD_GLOBAL    2        
RETURN_VALUE   1        
STORE_FAST     0, 2     *** differs ***
STORE_SUBSCR   1
```

Here is where it becomes evident that the second, clearer approach uses only four more bytecodes, and of the simple, fast `LOAD_FAST` / `STORE_FAST` variety. Static analysis thus shows no particular reason to fear additional memory allocation or other performance-killing side effects.

I then constructed two functions, very similar to one another, that the disassembler shows differ only in that the second one has an extra `LOAD_FAST` / `STORE_FAST` pair. I ran them 100,000,000 times, and compared their runtimes. They differed by just over 3 seconds in CPython 2.7.5, and about 1.5 seconds under PyPy 2.2.1 (based on Python 2.7.3). Even when you double those times (because you have two pairs), it's pretty clear those extra load/store pairs are not going to slow you down much.

Comment: Thanks!  This is awesome.  Using layman's approaches (%timeit and %memit) I can confirm that there is virtually no difference in time or memory usage.

Comment: @zhermes `%timeit` and `%memit` are a perfectly valid, delightfully empirical way to answer this question. If I had access to the full code and datasets, that's how I would have compared the different options. Static analysis and partial benchmarks are useful, but they're the end-way-around when simple benchmarking and/or profiling will do.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen either of those tools before --- so I'm really excited to know about them now!

Comment: They are awesome. Quick and effective. For situations where you're trying out a handful of different options, trying to find the fastest approach, the [benchmark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/benchmark) module is quite helpful. It's a little verbose, but does great things with randomization of runs and has a very neat, comparative table output.